# xmlhttp.responseText in Jquery is giving full html code as output

Tags: php, jquery

Take a look at this code:

```
function nbHintsearch1(counter) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (counter.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById("suggestion").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            $j(function () {
                var availableTags = [xmlhttp.responseText];

                function split(val) {
                    return val.split(/,\s*/);
                }

                function extractLast(term) {
                    return split(term).pop();
                }
                $j("#say")
                    .bind("keydown", function (event) {
                    if (event.keyCode === $j.ui.keyCode.TAB && $j(this).data("ui-autocomplete").menu.active) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                })
                    .autocomplete({
                    minLength: 0,
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        response($j.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                        availableTags, extractLast(request.term)));
                    },
                    focus: function () {
                        return false;
                    },
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        var terms = split(this.value);
                        terms.pop();
                        terms.push(ui.item.value);
                        terms.push("");
                        this.value = terms.join(", ");
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });


        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "msgto.php?msg=" + counter, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

In above code I've tried to output value in a textbox from few words one types in the textbox. In this it takes data from a page named msgto.php but it gives whole data as single value as full html code.

Can anyone tell me how I can get value of the availableTags variable as a string.

msgto.php looks like this:

```
<?php
$find=$_GET['msg'];$find = strtoupper($find); $find = strip_tags($find);
$find = trim($find);
include 'db.php'; 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE upper(fname) LIKE'%$find%'  or       upper(lname) LIKE'%$find%'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{$at="".$row['fname']." ".$row['lname']."";$js_array = json_encode($at);
echo "". $js_array . ",\n";}
?
```

>

Comment: if responseText contains full html, that means your server is returning full html. there isn't much mystery involved there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open developer console (F12 in Chrome, for instance) and in the "network" tab examine, what the real http request looks like. Maybe that PHP script is in different server directory than the browser expects it to be and the server is configured to return default page in such a case?